# MUIDataTables - Search always open

Tags: reactjs, search, input, datatable, mui-datatable

I'm using this lib https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables in react

My options:

```
const options = {
    customSearchRender: debounceSearchRender(500),
    searchOpen: true,
    // disable search icon
    search: false,
}
```

The icon search is disabled and search input init open

but when I click on viewColumns icon the search input closes

How I can prevent the search input never close?

Answer (score 1):

The "Search always open" functionality for [MUI-Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) is currently open for pull requests as of this writing (August 11, 2020) as seen [here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1344) and [here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1365). One of the contributors has suggested the use of a [custom toolbar](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#custom-components) as a workaround so you can have a custom search bar that is always open.

In addition, another workaround is to always have some text inside the search bar - this seems to prevent its closure (e.g., a white space). Moreover, they have a prop that is invoked when the search bar is closed, you can probably make use of this to do something when it does close.

```
onSearchClose: ()=>{
  //some logic
}
```

Comment: and you have also 'onSearchOpen' to toggle the search again